# How to build snappy-java under FreeBSD 8.1? (build error)

Tags: java, freebsd, cassandra

I'm trying to build snappy-java for FreeBSD 8.1 to use it with cassandra (can't enable columns compression without it).

Trying to build it from source and getting an error:

```
$ hg clone https://snappy-java.googlecode.com/hg/ snappy-java 
$ cd snappy-java 
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/openjdk6 && gmake
```

The process starts, but after some time i get the following error:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/openjdk6/include -Ilib/inc_mac -O2 -fPIC - 
fvisibility=hidden  -Ilib/include   -I"/usr/local/openjdk6/include/ 
freebsd" -Itarget/snappy-1.0.4 -o target/snappy-1.0.4-Default/ 
libsnappyjava.so target/snappy-1.0.4-Default/snappy-sinksource.o 
target/snappy-1.0.4-Default/snappy-stubs-internal.o target/ 
snappy-1.0.4-Default/snappy.o target/snappy-1.0.4-Default/ 
SnappyNative.o -shared -static 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/crtbeginT.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 can not be 
used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC 
/usr/lib/crtbeginT.o: could not read symbols: Bad value 
gmake: *** [target/snappy-1.0.4-Default/libsnappyjava.so] Error 1
```

So -fPIC is already ON... 
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can't enable columns compression without it

That is not quite true. DeflateCompressor is still available without the Snappy libraries. Do you require or prefer Snappy? If so, I would [add the downloadable .jar](http://code.google.com/p/snappy-java/downloads/list) from the Snappy project to your classpath. There is no need to perform your own build.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the -static from the compilerflags. You are building a shared libary.